# How automatically to update the format of a cell depending on the format of the reference cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, conditional-formatting, excel-indirect

I have a VLOOKUP formula and the result can be either a number or a percentage (this can even vary for the same cell depending on the value given by a drop-down list).

How can the format of the cell be automatically updated depending on the format of the "mother" cell?

Comment: Can you post the formula and some sample data? Will you number ever be between 0 and 1? If not, then just wrap an `If` statement around the `Vlookup` to check the outcome, and use `TEXT()` on the result?

Comment: You will need to do conditional formatting on the cell with the formula.

Comment: Formulas in and of themselves cannot read and/or set the format of a cell.  The method described by @BruceWayne will not set the format of the cell but change the number to text that looks like the correct number format.  It may work for you.

Comment: @ScottCraner - Can you do a conditional format that just follows another cell's format? I'm thinking of say `=CELL("format",A1)` to apply to `B1`?

Comment: @pnuts man y'all are dancing around an answer so I can't wait for more attempts/info from OP (\*cough cough hint hint\*) and someone can show me what y'all mean! : D

Answer (score 2):

A simplified example (since OP has not provided details):

[image: SO45471455 example]

The CF formula rule is:

```
=CELL("format",INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH(A9,H:H,0),9)))="P0"
```

and the format chosen `Percentage` (with decimal places set to `0`).